# Slidedown Toggle Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, slidedown

I don't know much Jquery and i'm stuck, can anyone help.

I boxes that slide down when click, however I want them so that only one can appear at once. At the moment when you open one, then the other they both stay open. Does anyone know how to make it so that when one is open and you click on the 2nd one, the 1st one shuts and the 2nd opens??

[Example](http://www.danielbenson.co)

Thanks.

Comment: can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

Please do not give external links, you should post code in your question. Giving a jsfiddle.net which reproduces your issue would be much better.

Coming to your problem,

Do slideToggle for both the elements in those click events.

```
$('#dropdown').on('click',function(){
  $('.dropdownwrap').slideDown();
  $('.dropdownwrap2').slideUp();
});

$('#dropdown2').on('click',function(){
  $('.dropdownwrap').slideUp();
  $('.dropdownwrap2').slideDown();
});
```

Comment: Will do :)

I have tried that but it just make it so that either button you click opens up .dropdownwrap2

Comment: @user2246968 - use `slideUp` & `slideDown` instead of `slideToggle`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Now it's not working at all. This is exactly how i would want it but can't get them to show a maximum of 1 at a time.

Sorry to be a pain

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`jquery Accordion`](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) 
 .its the best solution for your problem , because if your number of menus increses, the complexity for you code to slidetoggle will also increase. So let accordion to handle that for you

Answer (score 0):

If you show us your code, I can give you a more particular answer, but you should be able to use something like this:

```
$('.selector').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().slideToggle();
});
```

This way, when you click any element in the 'selector' class it focuses on $(this) element that you clicked, finds all of the other current siblings for the dropdowns and toggles all of them including the one you clicked. Thus, it should open the one you clicked and close all of the others.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [JQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/). It will be easier for you to manage if new sections are added, plus your titles are not being hidden now.

From their example code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    Section 1 Contents
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    Section 2 Contents
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    Section 3 Contents
  </div>
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div>
    Section 4 Contents
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**[UPDATE]**
In replay to [user2246968](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2246968/user2246968) comment:
Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6MUz7/) it's a quick workaround in the same structure of your code, but still I would recommend you to give some time checking out [jQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/).

Comment: I would like a navigation bar with the buttons to make the animations (like the example i provided)...

So when you click 'about' the about section will appear from the top and then clicking contact the about section will go and the contact section will slide down..

Can this be done using the code above?

Comment: Yes it can be done, and check the post update if you don't want to change your code's structure.